# Spying an AsyncTask doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mockito, android-testing

I am testing an `AsyncTask`. I want to stub an `HttpURLConnection` to return my mocked object. This is how I do it (`PackageDownloader` represents an `AsyncTask`):

```
 ...
 PackageDownloader packageDownloader = new PackageDownloader();
 packageDownloader.setParameters(URL, downloadFolder, downloadProgressCallback);
 PackageDownloader mPackageDownloader = spy(packageDownloader);
 HttpURLConnection connectionMock = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
 doReturn(0).when(connectionMock).getContentLength();
 doReturn(connectionMock).when(mPackageDownloader).createConnection(Mockito.any(URL.class));
 mPackageDownloader.execute();
 mPackageDownloader.get();
```

This is `PackageDownloader`:

```
public HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    return connection;
}

@Override
protected DownloadResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    URL downloadUrl = new URL(downloadUrlString);
    connection = createConnection(downloadUrl);
    long totalBytes = connection.getContentLength();
    ...
```

Here, createConnection returns real, not mocked object, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I mock `packageDownloader`'s `createConnection` method to return `connectionMock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a solution, though haven't found an explanation why it works so.
The reason nothing worked was that `doInBackground` method is async, I assume, so I had to call it directly via reflection, like so:

```
 Method method = mPackageDownloader.getClass().getMethod("doInBackground", Void[].class);
 method.invoke(mPackageDownloader, new Void[] {null});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use robolectric to test the asynctask rather than reflection. Following the `ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks()` should invoke the `doInBackground()` method.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AcknowledgeAppRemovedTaskTest {

    @Test
    public void execute_shouldOpenInputStreamOfConnection() throws IOException {
        DownloadTask spy = spy(new DownloadTask());
        HttpURLConnection connectionMock = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        doReturn(connectionMock).when(spy).createConnection(any(URL.class));

        spy.execute();
        ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();
        verify(connectionMock).getInputStream();
    }
}


class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {}

    public HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = createConnection(new URL("https://www.google.com/"));
            urlConnection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAsyncTaskTest.java

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/mqF21aqTi5g